# Verificar retorno $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, ajax

Preciso saber se retornou algo do banco de dados. Alguma sugestão?

```
var url = "agenda_salao_pesquisa.php?dataReserva="+busca;

$.getJSON(url, function(result) {
 //preciso saber se veio algo da consulta
            $.each(result, function(i, field) {

                var id = field.id;
                var dataReserva = field.dataReserva;
                var horaReserva =  field.horaReserva;
                var unidade = field.unidade;
                var responsavel = field.responsavel;
                var salao = field.salao;
   });
});
```

Comment: @ValdeirPsr nada acontece. Na verdade eu preciso preencher uma div caso não retorne nada.

Comment: a requisição traz algum valor ou retorna um valor em branco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função do método `$.getJSON` só vai ser executada se vier um objeto JSON válido. Para verificar se deu algum erro, veio vazio, ou um JSON inválido, você precisa adicionar o *callback* `.fail` ao método (a partir da versão 3 do jQuery):

### Versão 3.0 ou maior:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(result) {
   console.log("Deu certo. JSON válido!"); // aqui é a função success
})
.fail(function() {
   console.log("Deu erro. Veio nada, veio JSON inválido etc");
});
```

### Versão anterior a 3.0:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(result) {
   console.log("Deu certo. JSON válido!"); // aqui é a função success
})
.error(function() {
   console.log("Deu erro. Veio nada, veio JSON inválido etc");
});
```

Informações completas você pode consultar a [**página oficial do método**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

Comment: perfeito !!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `if(result){}`

Ele vai retornar `true` se o retorno **Não for: **

- null
- undefined
- NaN
- empty string ("")
- 0
- false

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515310/is-there-a-standard-function-to-check-for-null-undefined-or-blank-variables-in)

Comment: Eu preciso saber se não retornou nada, fiz if(!result){} e fiz como voce falou porem com else e nada

Comment: você já deu um `console.log(result)` para ver o que está vindo?

Comment: nao vem nada quando o resultado é vazio, quando coloco um parametro que retorna algo vem certinho